# stamp or label a FHIR resource

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have to do a job with a patient resource. So I would like to ask the FHIR server for all patients where some kind of stamp or label is not present or empty. Do the job and mark the patient with job = done.

Are there any standard features that I can use? tag or token?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource.meta.tag would fit the bill.  It's commonly used to manage workflow, which - from your description - sounds like what you're doing.